# Aurora MySQL - failed to delete a record

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, mysql-workbench, amazon-aurora

Today I failed to delete a record from a table in my database. I tried on both of my database management applications in MAC: `MySQL Pro` and `MySQLWorkbench`, but each of them created different error!

`MySQL Pro`

[image: Error in MySQL Pro]

`MySQLWorkbench`

[image: Error in MySQLWorkbench]

For both MySQL Pro and MySQLWorkbench, I am sure that I am log in using primary instance's link (not replica's) with user having DELETE privilege on this database.

Why the same database responds 2 different errors?

What settings should I look at in order to fix this?

Comment: By any chance, do you have Data API enabled? If yes, you could try to run this exact same query on AWS RDS console.

Comment: You appear to be connecting to the read-only endpoint of your cluster, or to a node in your cluster that is functioning as a read replica. Make sure you are connecting to the primary cluster endpoint if you want to perform any sort of create/update/delete functions. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.Overview.Endpoints.html#Aurora.Overview.Endpoints.Types

Answer (score 0):

I have checked all foreign keys referring to the record ID which I currently want to delete. It looks good.

Then I delete all records in the "child" tables referring to the ID of the record; and go back to delete the record -> it works!

I remember I had once changed a foreign keys from CASCADE for ON DELETE/UPDATE to NULL for ON DELETE/UPDATE, then I rolled back (CASCADE for ON DELETE/UPDATE). Not sure if that is the root cause.

Anyhow, I get my job done and I'd like to confirm that I have been working with the primary Aurora instance since the beginning, not replica.